# there is no data binding package in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, data-binding

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tk.f12developers.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
}
```

**I did include data binding**

[this is what I got inside java generated packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZTAh.png)

I did clean project and rebuild too

Comment: remove `dataBinding { enabled true }` from the gradle and try

Comment: Please share the error image as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please replace in app module `Gradle` file:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
```

to:

```
android {
....
}
```

For example:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "tk.f12developers.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are used mvvm architecture plese reffer this link https://www.androidhive.info/android-working-with-databinding/ .